# Parse JSON with python UDF in PIG

Tags: python, json, apache-pig

I have a table of the following form

```
(field1,field2)
...
```

with field2 being a json with an arbitrary number of (key,value);

What I want is "explode" each dictionary and get an output table of the form:

```
 (field1, key_1,value_1)
 (field1, key_2,value_2)
 (field1, key_3,value_3)
 ...
```

with (key_1, value_1) ... are the (key, value) pairs in the dictionary field2. Likewise for the other rows in the original table.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: So far my approach and it seems to work; I read the json and add to a bag then I flatten